# Geocoding output 3 times the same lat/lng

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

I geocoded some hardcoded adresses with the server based geocoding:

```
for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {

    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {

        var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        var lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

        latlng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
        markerLocations.push(latlng);

        //}
        for (var b=0; b < markerLocations.length; b++)
        {
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerLocations[b].lat, markerLocations[b].lng),
                map: map,
            }))
        };
    });
}
```

Hardcoded Adresses:

```
var addresses = [
    ['Hamburg'],
    ['The Grand Bhagwati,ahmedabad'],
    ['Global Pagoda Road, Gorai Island, Borivali West, Mumbai, Maharashtra'],
    ['583 Orchard Rd, B1-25, Singapore'],
    ['Norway, Oslo']
];
```

My problem is now that I get the arrays multiplied because 2 for loops are inserted. I would like to get an output at the end from the lat, lng 1 time only and not the same lat/lng coordinates 3 or 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with each loop all your markers get added again from the `markerLocations` array. You can use a simple function to resolve this like below-

```
for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {

    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
        var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        var lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

        latlng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
        addMarker(latlng);
    });
}

function addMarker(latlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(latlng.lat, latlng.lng), 
                        map: map }));
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem with the redundant data stopped but now i cant use my distance calculator anymore. The compute distance between function wont compare my fixed markers with the marker you can set. Because i get a TypeError that the markers.getPosition isnt anymore a function.

Comment: Please share the code that you are using to calculate the distance.

Comment: for (var i=0; i< markers.length; i++)
{ if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markers[i].getPosition(),marker.getPosition()) <= radius)
    {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
    
    }
    else
    {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
   }

Comment: @Shadog Please update your code in the above question itself, also please show where you have defined the `markers` array and the `marker` object you are using in the `for` loop.